# Where is this? (Likely Alpine lake.)

Tags: where-on-earth

[image]

notice the autoroute guardrail.  Goog image search didn't help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lake Lucerne, perhaps Meggen looking towards Burgenstock

Comment: Close - [this Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/@47.0001156,8.3116385,3a,75y,66.7h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1syMVhKzMMK9VFI9nq-N8glg!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo3.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DyMVhKzMMK9VFI9nq-N8glg%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D57.727566%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656) is just north of Hergiswil, looking north-east towards Burgenstock.